# Prevent optimizations for one operation in c

Tags: c, floating-point, c99

I'm implementing an algorithm using compensated summation to reduce the amount of roundoff errors adding up. I'm wondering if I can tell the compiler somehow not to optimize the floating point operations in one specific part of the code. More precisely, I'd like to keep the order of operations preserved. Here is an example code snippet (all variables are `double`):

```
while(1){
    a = y;
    e = e + d;
    y = a + e;
    e = e + (a - y);
}
```

I'm worried that the last line could be *optimized* to read `e=e-e` or `e = (e+a)-y`. In which circumstances could this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Does it actually get optimized? Typically, compilers won't use normal mathematical properties to optimize floating-point arithmetic *because* of the rounding errors you mention.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering. Is a bracket enough to prevent rearranging of floating point operations by the compiler?

Comment: AFAIK it won't optimize/rearrange even *without* brackets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the compiler claims to be IEEE 754 compliant, then it has to perform the operations exactly as you wrote them - unless it can prove that the result will be the same (in which case the different calculation will not hurt you).

Sometimes this makes code run slower than it would if the compiler would be allowed to give slightly different results. And some compilers have an option to allow the compiler that kind of optimisation. If your compiler has such options, you need to turn them off.

The compiler *must* respect parentheses. For example, in "e = e + (a - y);" it *must* subtract y from a, add the result to e, and store the sum into e.

Comment: Thanks. For gcc, am I right in assuming that this would be optimized only if `-fassociative-math` is turned on (i.e. not with `-O3`)?

Comment: The C standard disallows this optimization (no need to appeal to IEEE-754), even without parentheses.

Comment: @hanno Yes, GCC includes some optimization options that violate the C spec, and are disabled by default on all `-O` optimization levels for that reason. Most of them can be turned on with the `-ffast-math` option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strictly standard way to prevent optimization (in general). However, if using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, you could use [#pragma GCC optimize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas) or the `optimize` [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes).

BTW, I am not sure it is worth the trouble. You could look at the lower-level Gimple (perhaps using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or some `-fdump-tree-*`), or at the generated assembler code (use `-fverbose-asm` to get a more readable assembler ode).

Comment: The standard itself prevents this optimization, unless you license it by compiler flags or pragmas.